# Hacer un modificar y eliminar desde android estudio una base de datos en SQL Server?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy creando una app, que haga un registro de productos y lo hace a la perfección, luego lo busque los productos y también lo hace el problema empieza al momento de querer modificar ya que lo intente, pero el código que hice no hace nada solo me dice que fue modificado pero no lo fue y no he podido hacer tampoco el eliminar, y el código es el siguiente, necesito que el método modificar y eliminar...

Estoy creando una app, que haga un registro de productos y lo hace a la perfección, luego lo busque los productos y también lo hace el problema empieza al momento de querer modificar ya que lo intente, pero el código que hice no hace nada solo me dice que fue modificado pero no lo fue y no he podido hacer tampoco el eliminar, y el código es el siguiente, necesito que el método modificar y eliminar...

```
   package com.example.e_foot;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class registro extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txt_id,txt_nombre,txt_descripcion,txt_precio;
    private Button agregar,modificar,buscar,eliminar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

        txt_id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_idAg);
        txt_nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_nombreAg);
        txt_descripcion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_descripcion);
        txt_precio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_precioAg);

        agregar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_agregar);
        agregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                agregarComida();
            }
        });

        buscar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_buscar);
        buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Buscar();
            }
        });

        modificar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_moficar);
        modificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Modificar();

            }
        });

    }

    //Conexion a la base de datos
    public Connection connection(){

        Connection connection = null;
        try{

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DESKTOP-6G1JRJF:1433;databaseName=EfootDataBase;user=adminEFOOT;password=321");

        }catch (Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return connection;
    }

    //agregar
    public void agregarComida() {

        String codigo = txt_id.getText().toString();
        String nombreP = txt_nombre.getText().toString();
        String ingredientes = txt_descripcion.getText().toString();
        String precioP = txt_precio.getText().toString();

        if(!codigo.isEmpty() && !nombreP.isEmpty() && !ingredientes.isEmpty() && !precioP.isEmpty()){

            try{

                PreparedStatement pst = connection().prepareStatement("insert into Productos values(?,?,?,?)");

                int precio = Integer.parseInt(txt_precio.getText().toString());
                int codigoP = Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText().toString());
                pst.setInt(1,codigoP);
                pst.setString(2,txt_nombre.getText().toString());
                pst.setString(3,txt_descripcion.getText().toString());
                pst.setInt(4,precio);
                pst.executeUpdate();

                txt_id.setText("");
                txt_nombre.setText("");
                txt_descripcion.setText("");
                txt_precio.setText("");

                Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch (Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(this, "Llene todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    //Buscar
    public void Buscar(){

        int save_id = Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText().toString());

        try{

            Statement stm = connection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE ID LIKE " + save_id);
            while (rs.next()){

                txt_nombre.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));
                txt_descripcion.setText(rs.getString("descripcion"));
                txt_precio.setText(rs.getString("precio"));

            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    //Modificar
    public void  Modificar(){

        int save_id = Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText().toString());


        try{

            Statement stm = connection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE ID LIKE " + save_id);

            while (rs.next()){

                    txt_nombre.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));
                    txt_descripcion.setText(rs.getString("descripcion"));
                    txt_precio.setText(rs.getString("precio"));

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Modificado corrctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }catch (Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: tiene que ponerla update, tiene select

Answer (score 0):

fijate en tu funcion `Modificar()`, estas haciendo un `select` y lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
update "UPDATE "NOMBRE DE TABLA" SET "NOMBRE COLUMNA"= "NUEVO VALOR" WHERE "COLUMNA" = "CONDICION PARA ACTUALIZAR"".
```